# When testing with WatiN: "'DebuggerDisplayProxy()' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'"

Tags: watin

```
FrameworkActionsLink = CurrentBuyerSite.BuyerWorkAreaFrame.Link(Find.ById("actions"));
```

I have code which finds a link  element by finding by ID.

The HTML on the page is:

```
<a id="actions" href="Javascript:ShowMenuItem('options','actions'); ... >
```

I have excluded the full Javascript code in the href where you see "...".

On test execution, sometimes this code works correctly, but sometimes I get the following error:

> 'DebuggerDisplayProxy()' threw an exception of type
>   'System.InvalidCastException'

It's a pretty straightforward bit of code, I just wondered if anyone had experienced similar problems or error messages. Do you think this is an issue with the WatiN tool, the web application, the internet browser, or perhaps something else entirely?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following code:

```
FrameworkActionsLink = (WatiN.Core.Link)CurrentBuyerSite.BuyerWorkAreaFrame.Link(Find.ById("actions"));
```

I'm pretty sure that it doesn't like the link being `JavaScript:...`

**Edit**: Try maybe this:

```
CurrentBuyerSite.Eval("ShowMenuItem('options','actions'); ...");
```

Comment: I made that change but it did not make a difference to the tests - I ran the test three times, but still getting inconsistent results - it passed once but failed twice.

Is there anything else I could try, or any other workarounds?

Comment: Will give this a try when I'm back in work on Friday. Have been unable to access stackoverflow.com during work hours because the company network is tied into a university network which for some inexplicable reason has blocked access to stackoverflow.com. Thanks for the help.

Comment: t3hnoob, I gave this a try with a similar test scenario, but unfortunately I'm still getting the exact same error inconsistently. First time, it was successful, second time I ran the the test it fails with error message, "InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code" ... "Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to interface type 'mshtml.IHTMLDocument2'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID" ... "failed due to the following error. No such interface supported".

Comment: What I should note though is that the error message I just posted above is the same message that appears when WatiN attempts to click on the Link element. I didn't post this error message originally because I assumed this error message was only appearing as a result of not being able to identify the Link element which throws the System.InvalidCastException error message.

Comment: I'm going to try it with CurrentBuyerSite.ContainingBrowse.CurrentBrowser.Eval(...). 
I'm thinking that perhaps the issue is with the frame element on the page? Worth a try.

Comment: is it in the same frame? and can you get the frame's url ? i have no idea though..

Answer (score 2):

What runner are you using? if nUnit 64bit then try 32bit or other runner.

Maybe the issue is that page didn't fully download and that makes problem with javascript function, try replace Click() for ClickNoWait().

Comment: I'm using the Visual Studio test runner (using the VS test framework). It's a 32-bit install. OS is 64-bit.

Comment: I tried to replicate error and couldn't make it. This would be helpfull if you could post the whole example of code.

Comment: The code is rather large. But all I'm doing is attempting to find the element (I've specified the frame it is contained within) and click it.