# Browser Tests using Coded UI

Tags: watin, coded-ui-tests

How do I write the following tests which is written in Watin using CodedUI

I am trying to learn CodedUI but really struggling

```
[Test]

public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()

{

using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))

 {

   browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");

   browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

  Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find a bit of help from one of these links:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gautamg/archive/2009/12/18/why-is-coded-ui-test-generated-code-not-a-straight-line-code.aspx - this is a blog post on MSDN that talks about the code generated by recording a test.  It has a sample project attached you might consider looking at.

As I said in your other question, the best way is to create recordings.  There is a nice little walkthrough also on MSDN, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff977233.aspx.  This one shows you the process of recording a test and generating and maintaining the code for it.

I would strongly encourage you to thoroughly read those two articles.

Comment: Thanks Vi3GameHkr , I will go thru these. I tried recording the tests but the code generated was very overwhelming, hopefully i will start getting a hang of it in a couple of days

Comment: In that case, the first article will be the most helpful to you.  If I have a tip I could pass along from my experience, it's to perform as few actions as possible in each method, then practice re-use!

Answer (score 0):

WatiN and the Visual Studio Coded UI tests are different. 'Coded UI tests' refer to Visual Studio's own UI testing tools. WatiN is a different test framework.

Personally, I don't like WatiN because it takes a long time to write tests and it does not playback tests reliably (at least from my experience). The Visual Studio Coded UI tests I prefer more because they provide a test recorder which auto-generates the test code and a a graphical test editor, while still giving you the flexibility to edit the test code yourself.

I have found more success with Visual Studio coded UI tests. The best thing you can do to get started with creating tests using VS Coded UI tests is to read the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726), particularly be sure to read the '[Anatomy of a Coded UI Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398062)' to get a hang for the generated code. Read each article in the documentation as it goes through the whole process, from recording tests to editing, maintaining them and best practices.

Also, make sure you have downloaded Visual Studio Feature Pack 2 to be able to use the graphical test editor which is useful when creating and editing tests.

The really off-putting thing about WatiN (apart from its unreliability) is that it doesn't really have a proper documentation, so it can be difficult to know how to handle elements. It's my opinion that you should ditch WatiN, and go with the Visual Studio coded UI tests, if they are available to you. The great thing about the Visual Studio coded UI tests is that it can deal with minor changes to the UI and automatically adapts. WatiN can do no such thing.

Comment: Ciaran G , what issues did you face with WatiN

Comment: I personally seemed to get error messages on an inconsistent, almost random basis. Often, tests would fail to find elements on pages for no valid reason - it would instead throw errors, like the ones I detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153205/when-testing-with-watin-debuggerdisplayproxy-threw-an-exception-of-type-s

Comment: Surprisingly , WatiN worked seamlessly with me and I am pretty happy about it . The only reason I am trying to explore Coded UI is because my clients here are not open to open source. Now we have a custom framework built in excel which generates a test script ( excel file). This file is read by QTP engine and it performs the actions and validations on the application. I have sucessfully built the same kind of engine in WatiN and it works seamlessly.

Comment: Now since you seem to be good at Coded UI let me ask you this? is it possible to do that using Coded UI at all , read instructions from excel and then perform those actions on application. I am sorry but i don't want to do any record and play. I have been looking for an API which is similar to selenium , watin , which gives me capability to 

1. Locate elements on a web page
2. Interact with located elements ( click , read , select , submit)
3. Run javascript